# Bash script for splitting and moving files. Files moved before split is completed?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of large csv files named like `01-letters-letters.csv`, `02-letters-letters.csv`, etc. I want to split up and put into a subfolder. So I inline this script:

```
for i in *.csv; do 
    split -l 600000 "$i"; 
    for j in x*; 
        do mv "$j" chunked/"$j-${i:0:2}"; 
    done; 
done;
```

But I notice that files are already moved to the subfolder before the split on the first file is completed.

Is this normal?

Comment: That's not possible. You're not doing anything in the background, each statement waits for the previous one to finish.

Comment: yes I realized I made a mistake. The first file is just way smaller than the rest, so I thought it had not finished splitting... I feel silly now ;(

Comment: side-note: You don't need the `;` as a command delimiter in bash unless you put multiple commands in one line.